# Fabricjs removed selected object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

How can I remove a selected Object in Fabric js

Currently I can remove one selected object like following:

```
function removeCurrentObject(canvas) {
    $('#remove-current-object').click(function() {
        canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
    });
}
```

But how can I check wether the user selectes more objects and remove them on an Event(click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removeCurrentObject(canvas) {
$('#remove-current-object').click(function() {
  if(canvas.getActiveGroup()) {
    var objs = canvas.getActiveGroup();
    canvas.discardActiveGroup();
    objs.forEachObject(function(o) {
    canvas.remove(o)
   });
  } else {
   canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject());
  }
  });
}
```

check if any active group there, if present remove one by one object from group